# Light flickers a bit when I turn on an hand blender. What can be the case?

Tags: electrical, lighting

The lights over my stove flickers when I use an hand blender. 
The power for the hand blender come in a different circuit from the switch board.

The light as far as I know is led.

What can be happening? how can I solve it?

Comment: What kind of light is it? Incandescent? CFL? LED?

Comment: Could be vibration transmitted to the bulbs? Test by using the same receptacle, but place the blending container off the counter, e.g., on a stool or chair.  If the light still trembles then it is not vibration but electrical.

Comment: The lights are led as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the LED power supply picks up some of the electrical noise (radio frequency interference or RFI) generated by the blender motor, and it "tricks" the regulator in the supply to cause the flicker.

If the flicker is not annoying, then there is no reason to do anything, but you can add RFI filtering to the blender and/or the LED lamp. The filter can be a [simple plug adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I9B1KQ), or perhaps winding wires around [ferrite beads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DF09VEC). (The links are given to show sample devices, not necessarily recommendations.) Depending on proximity, frequency etc., both might be needed.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into your suggestion. The flicker is quite strong. Can it damage the light? Any chance it's an electrical installation poorly designed?